# Set the marker size for a given point in the Char Point DevExpress

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

Can you please explain me how can I set the marker size for a given point when using a [Point Cahrt](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxChartDemos/PointAndLineTypes/PointView) .
I also want to set the benchmark graph to customized point.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WebChartControl does not allow you to specify a point marker size for a specific point.
The questions was answered [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T324729)